# Revert or reset permissions of extensions

Tags: macos, permission, plugins

I accidentally approved the request of Weather extension to access my location info on macOS 10.14.6. I want to revert or reset this. How can I do that? Is there a way other than reinstalling macOS?

Comment: In systems preferences, there is an Extensions panel where I think you can turn off or on mac extensions.  Go to extensions in system preferences.

Comment: I don't want to turn off this extension. I want to use it, but I don't want it to have that permission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

System Preferences → Security & Privacy → Privacy, Location services tab.

[image: System Preferences → Security & Privacy → Privacy, Location services tab]